# Best practices for Database Migrations in Production in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, continuous-integration, entity-framework-migrations

I am developping an ASP.Net Core application, backed with a PostgreSQL database.

So far, my application is hosted on my personal VPS, but I would like to migrate on Azure, and I don't know how to handle the DB migrations over there.

My database scheme is handled by Entity Framework Core and mapped with POCOs.
As explained in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/), when I want to change my SQL scheme, I update the POCOs, create a migration C# file through the `dotnet ef migration create` command, and apply them through the `Database.Migrate()` command at runtime.
This is defined by [Applying migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying#apply-migrations-at-runtime), however as stated:

> While productive for local development and testing of migrations, this approach is inappropriate for managing production databases.

There is a paragraph about using [SQL Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying#sql-scripts), but nothing really about "How to apply migrations scripts in CI/CD pipeline".

Of course, I had a look to the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app) on Microsoft docs about how to deploy and ASP.Net Core app + SQL DB on Azure, but there is nothing about DB migrations (the migrations of the production DB are applied through CLI from local computer ...).

Isn't there a specific service on Azure allowing us to apply the DB migrations?

I know this question is specific neither to Azure, nor to .NET apps, but I was afraid my question would be too "broad".

Also, when looking for "DB migrations" on Google, most results are concerning the migration from a given DB to another (or from a vendor to another), which is not the same.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a specific service in Azure that manages your DB migrations.

From experience, it's usually managed by generating the migration SQL (`dotnet ef migrations script`), reviewing it and then running it manually or saving to a file that is then executed as a part of the CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is exactly "how do I execute the migration scripts as a part of the CI/CD pipeline?"

Comment: Well that's up to you. You can automate the part which generates an SQL script, saves it and runs it, you can use the CLI or you can do it via `Database.Migrate()`, this is up to you and your specific use case.

Comment: I usually have a separate console application which does all the db things I need so I can use it both locally and via CI/CD.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are looking for Azure Database Migration Service. It has two main mode, online and offline mode depending on your migration strategy.
It is compatible with PostgresSQL et should allow migration to managed Postgres (Single or Flexible Server).

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/database-migration/#overview

Once your migration is done, you can then point your connection string to your newly migrated DB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the tool you indicated to me is aimed at migrating from a DB to another DB, or from a vendor to Azure. My request concerned scheme migrations, which can occur regularly in the development loop. My last paragraph was specifically aimed at disambiguating these two notions, which makes me think maybe you didn't read my question until the end.